# How to Use an array of strings in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, array

I writte the following script

load function should set the array `disk[a]=1` and `disk[b]=2` and so on

Then the function out should print the array `${disk[a]}` , and `${disk[b]}` , and so on

But what we get from function out is always the number `4`

Instead, I want to get the following:

```
1
2
3
4
```

What is wrong here ?

How to fix it so function out will print:

```
1
2
3
4
```

the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function load
{
  counter=1
  for input in a b c d
  do
    disk[$input]=$counter
    let counter=$counter+1
    echo ${disk[$input]}
  done
}


function out
{
  counter=1
  for input in  a b c d
  do
    echo ${disk[$input]}
    let counter=$counter+1
  done
}

echo "run function load"
load
echo "run function out"
out
```

the output:

```
./test
run function load
1
2
3
4
run function out
4
4
4
4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash arrays are *indexed arrays* by default:

> An indexed array is created automatically if any variable is assigned to using the syntax `name[subscript]=value`

... but you are using letters as the index, so you probably want an associative array, which means you need an:

```
declare -A disk
```

before calling the functions.

Comment: what actually declare -A do?

Comment: @yael, it declares an associative array

Answer (score 6):

Look at what happens to the array when you initialize it:

```
$ i=0; for k in a b c d; do A[$k]=$((i++)); done; declare -p A
declare -a A=([0]="3")
```

Only one element is present, and it has the index zero.

By default, arrays are indexed *by numbers*, and the numerical values of the indices you used happened to be all zero. Actually, in an arithmetic context, like the subscript of a regular array, a string is taken as the name of a variable, and the value of that variable is used. So, if we set `a`, `b`... to numbers, then we get something different:

```
$ a=123; b=456; c=789; d=999; i=0;
$ for k in a b c d; do A[$k]=$((i++)); done;
$ declare -p A
declare -a A=([123]="0" [456]="1" [789]="2" [999]="3")
```

To actually use the strings themselves as indices, declare the array as an associative array first with `declare -A arrayname` or `typeset -A arrayname`:

```
$ unset A; declare -A A; i=0;
$ for k in a b c d; do A[$k]=$((i++)); done; declare -p A
declare -A A=([a]="0" [b]="1" [c]="2" [d]="3" )
```